# Can M-alternating path end by an M-saturated vertix?

Tags: graph-theory

As defined in "Combinatorics and Graph Theory" by Harris et al. 
"Given a graph G and a matching M, an M-alternating path is a path in G where
the edges alternate between M-edges and non-M-edges. An M-augmenting path
is an M-alternating path where both end vertices are M-unsaturated."

It is not clear for me whether this allows the last vertex in an M-alternating path to be M-saturated.

Comment: Yes, that is allowed (since it is not forbidden in the definition of alternating path). In an alternating path both endpoints may be saturated or unsaturated (independent from each other).

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk Thanks, Another question, If I start with an edge in M, am I free to end with an edge in M or not?

Comment: Yes, you are...